# Getting error while using activeClassname on NavLink, using typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am getting the error "Property 'activeClassName' does not exist on type IntrinsicAttributes", while using activeClassname on NavLink, using typescript. Find the code below,

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

import { Container, Selector } from "./styles";

const DefaultHeader: React.FC = () => {
```

Im just trying to use activeClassname, but don't know how to
type it correctly,

```
  return (
    <Container>
      <NavLink to='/headers' activeClassName='wasd'>
        <Selector>Headers</Selector>
      </NavLink>      
    </Container>
  );
}; 

export default DefaultHeader;
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you use React router version 6 then activeClassName is no longer more.
> you can simply use className.

ex-

```
 return (
 <Container>
  <NavLink to='/headers' className={(props)=>props.isActive ? "wasd" : ""}>
                       or
  <NavLink to="/headers" className={({isActive})=>isActive? "wasd" :"">
   // direct use destructure

    <Selector>Headers</Selector>
  </NavLink>      
</Container>
 );
}; 
export default DefaultHeader;
```

> In Version 5 is still the same

```
<NavLink to="/faq" activeClassName="selected">
  FAQs
</NavLink>
```